# How to sum overtime hours users spent on work

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, date-arithmetic

I have two SQL Server tables `employee(empid, empname)` and `employee_movements(empid, MoveDatetime)` which I store employees actions from fingerprint by datetime, I want to count hours every employee spent after work from 03:30pm until 6:00am in the next day

So if I have this data

```
| EmpID | MoveDateTime       |
|-------|--------------------|
| 1     | 01.01.2020 3:30pm  |
| 1     | 01.01.2020 5:30pm  |
| 1     | 01.01.2020 11:00pm |
| 1     | 02.01.2020 02:30am |
| 2     | 01.01.2020 4:00am  |
| 2     | 01.01.2020 10:15am |
| 1     | 02.01.2020 4:00pm  |
| 1     | 02.01.2020 5:00pm  |
```

I should get this result

```
| EmpID | Entrance           | Departure          | Actual_hours |
|-------|--------------------|--------------------|--------------|
| 1     | 01.01.2020 3:30PM  | 01.01.2020 5:30PM  | 2.00         |
| 1     | 01.01.2020 11:00PM | 02.01.2020 2:30Am  | 3.5          |
| 2     | 01.01.2020 4:00AM  | 01.01.2020 10:15PM | 7.25         |
| 1     | 02.01.2020 04:00am | 02.01.2020 5:00am  | 01.00        |
```

I tried this code

```
with cte as 
(
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [EmpID], cast ([MoveDateTime] as Date) 
                               ORDER BY [MoveDateTime]) as rn
  FROM employee_movements t1 
)  
SELECT c1.EmpID, c1.rn,c2.rn,
       cast (c1.MoveDateTime as Date) as the_day,c1.MoveDateTime as enterance,c2.MoveDateTime as departure, cast (sum (DATEDIFF (S, c1.MoveDateTime, c2.MoveDateTime)/3600.00) as decimal(18,2)) as Actual_Hours
FROM cte c1
left JOIN cte c2
  ON 
c1.rn = c2.rn -1 AND 
c1.EmpID = c2.EmpID and c1.rn % 2 <> 0 
and (cast (c1.MoveDateTime as Date)=cast (c2.MoveDateTime as Date) ) or (c2.rn=1 and cast(dateadd(day,1,c1.MoveDateTime) as date)= cast(c2.MoveDateTime as Date) and (cast(c2.MoveDateTime as time) between '00:00:00' and '06:00:00')) 
AND c2.rn % 2 = 0
 where c2.rn is not null
GROUP BY c1.EmpID,c1.rn,c2.rn,
         cast (c1.MoveDateTime as Date) ,c1.MoveDateTime,c2.MoveDateTime
```

Which I got from it the in and out of every employee and count of hours, but the problem it is partitioned by one day doesn't return the second case because the employee still in work and left on the next day.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results, as tabular text.

Comment: Day of overtime starts at 3:30pm and ends on 6:00am on the next day I want to sum all hours between every fingerprint actions of the employee  by day .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a starter: you can interleave the rows using window functions to generate the in/out pairs:

```
select *
from (
    select empid, movedatetime as dt_in,
            lead(movedatetime) over(partition by empid order by movedatetime) as dt_out,
            row_number() over(partition by empid order by movedatetime) rn
        from employee_movements 
) t
where rn % 2 = 1
```

Then we need to comput the overtime for each date range. SQL Server is not that good at date arithmetics; if you don't have too many rows to proceed at once, the simplest approach might be brute force: enumerate all the minutes between the two dates, the count only those that do not belong to the working hours.

So:

```
with 
    data as (
        select empid, movedatetime as dt_in,
            lead(movedatetime) over(partition by empid order by movedatetime) as dt_out,
            row_number() over(partition by empid order by movedatetime) rn
        from employee_movements 
    ),
    cte as (
        select empid, dt_in, dt_out, dt_in as dt 
        from data 
        where rn % 2 = 1
        union all
        select empid, dt_in, dt_out, dateadd(minute, 1, dt) 
        from cte 
        where dateadd(minute, 1, dt) < dt_out
    )
select empid, dt_in, dt_out, 
    sum(
        case when convert(time, dt) >= '06:00:00' and convert(time, dt) < '15:30:00' 
        then 0 
        else 1 
    end) ot_minutes
from cte
group by empid, dt_in, dt_out
order by empid, dt_in
option (maxrecursion 0)
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddlde](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=82c453c310b0486e189a21d343f56d68)**:

```
empid | dt_in                   | dt_out                  | ot_minutes
----: | :---------------------- | :---------------------- | ---------:
    1 | 2020-01-01 15:30:00.000 | 2020-01-01 17:30:00.000 |        120
    1 | 2020-01-01 23:00:00.000 | 2020-01-02 02:30:00.000 |        210
    1 | 2020-01-02 16:00:00.000 | 2020-01-02 17:00:00.000 |         60
    2 | 2020-01-01 04:00:00.000 | 2020-01-01 22:15:00.000 |        525
```

Comment: Thank you GMB , good job , but theres a missing thing It gives me line with dt_in 2020-10-13 and dt_out 2020-10-21 which crosses more than one day , but I want to sum overtime only for movements starting from first day at 15:30 till the next day at 6:00 at maximum and exlude Odd actions with null dt_out in this interval

Comment: @hussein.nagdy: I have no idea what you are saying. The data you are referring to is not part of your sample data, is it?

Comment: Actually it isn't in sample data but in my database this appears with me

Comment: @hussein.nagdy: that's my point... This query works for the sample data you provided. If you have a different use case, then you might want to ask a new question, providing proper sample data and desired results.